# xPath, selecting every child element

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following xPath query:

```
//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/p[1]/text()
```

This selects the first 'p' element inside the parent divs and ID. Is it possible to simply select all 'p' elements? I've made several attempts at this none of which work. Removing the object id does not appear to work, and removing the object (square brackets) does not work either.

Comment: You'll need to provide us a sample of XML/HTML (small enough to paste into the question itself) to test this against, as at the moment it's impossible for us to guess what will work and what won't.

Comment: Have you tried "//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/p" ?  Ef you want *all* p elements, regardless of where they are in the XML document, just do "//p"

Comment: Thanks @HaukurfHaf that works a treat

Answer (score 0):

@HaukurHaf Had the correct answer. The following selects all p elements in the nested elements.

```
//*[@id="shopMain"]/div/div/p
```